# LARAVEL 5 - host web server with API

Tags: .htaccess, api, laravel, server, http-status-code-403

I am trying to set me local project which works perfectly well on a host server (always data).

I made a project folder on the root (/project) of server where I uploaded all my files 
I copied public folder into /www

Exactly how explained on this tutorial :https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

First pages load perfectly, but when I am trying to connect with my api, the redirect URL returns a 403 Forbidden error 
My redirect url is htp://.......com/public/play
It works when it is localhost but not on my web server...

Should I put **www**/play as redirect URL?

Why can I access my view on first page but not after redirection from api?

Thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You are not may be copying the content of public folder in the www directory Like it said

> Next step is to copy all contents inside the /project/public directory
>   to www/ directory. The easy example is that, with the fresh Laravel 5
>   installation application, the project/public/index.php should be
>   copied to the www/index.php , have you got the point?

and you did

> I copied public folder into /www